# Distinct values from a nested list using lambda

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda, nested

I have a list of Documents which contains a list of DocumentGroups, and I want to select all the distinct DocumentGroups to perform an operation. Iterating through 2 loops is trivial, but I was not able to find out how to do that with lambda expressions. Could anyone provide some help?

Those are the classes

```
public class Document
{
     public int DocumentID {get; set;}

     public string DocumentName {get; set;}

     public List<DocumentGroup> DocumentGroups { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentGroup : IEquatable<DocumentGroup>
{
    public int DocumentGroupID { get; set; }

    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(DocumentGroup other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return other.DocumentGroupID == this.DocumentGroupID;
    }
}
```

That is the trivial code

```
List<DocumentGroup> distinctDocumentGroups = new List<DocumentGroup>();

foreach (Document d in documentList)
{
     foreach(DocumentGroup dg in d.DocumentGroups)
     { 
         if (!distinctDocumentGroups.Contains(dg))
             distinctDocumentGroups.Add(dg);
     }
}
```

Thanks,
Leandro Tavares

Comment: You implement `IEquatable` but don't override `GetHashCode`.  That's *very very* bad.  You *really* want to have a hash code implementation that is in sync with the definition of `Equals`.  You also should not have `Equals(DocumentGroup other)` have a different definition of equality than `Equals(object other)`.  That's *very* confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you just want a combination of `[SelectMany`][1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (to flatten the document list to a document group sequence) and then [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the distinct elements:

```
var documentGroups = documentList.SelectMany(d => d.DocumentGroups)
                                 .Distinct()
                                 .ToList();
```

You'll need to override `GetHashCode` in `DocumentGroup` as well, as noted by Servy. In this case that's trivial:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return DocumentGroupId;
}
```

Also note that having `DocumentGroupId` *mutable* while being the key for equality is worrying. If you can, change it to be immutable and pass the ID into the constructor.

Comment: @Servy: It will by the time the hash code has been fixed, which is presumably the intention.

Comment: It dind´t worked for me. The result list has more than one occurence of a DocumentGroup. I´ve checked the IEquatable implementation, and it is ok. Any ideia that was is may happening?

Comment: @LeandroTavares: I trust LINQ to Objects more than I trust your checking of your `IEquatable<T>` implementation, I'm afraid... have you now overridden `GetHashCode` appropriately?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, you are right. I´ve overrided the implementation of GetHashCode and it now works! Thanks for the help

Comment: @Servy Thanks! It was really necessary to override the GetHashCode. It it is also a very good practice!

Comment: @JonSkeet I´ve also forgot that for the equality comparison the Hashcode is evaluated, and only if its results is equal that Equals is evaluated. Thus, but must be implemented. I will also take your advice about changing Id to be immutable. Thank, once again!